# Error while making the call to AWS S3 bucket from Pyspark . AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

### The error is a Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o411.csv.

#### com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: fsdfewffsd, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: **Bad Request**, S3 Extended Request ID

I am on spark 3.0 preview version.
I started the pyspark session with `pyspark --packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3` command.

I have tried the following code below

```
hadoop_conf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key",ACCESS_KEY)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key",SECRET_KEY)
```

Followed by a call to the bucket as such, the following line throws the error.

```
sdf = spark.read.csv("s3a://aai-team/neighbourhoods.csv")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exact same issue today.
Just solved it with setSystemProperty ->

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("app").getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
```

and then the hadoop_conf just like yours.

Comment: thanks a lot! i've searching on all the [web](https://www.google.com)!